# Switching fxml scenes with setScene hangs on Mac

Tags: java, swing, javafx, deadlock

We have a JDialog that contains a single stage with multiple scenes.  Each scene has a next button.  When the user clicks "next" we call stage.setScene.  This works fine on Windows and Linux, but on Mac, setScene never returns.  The application hangs, and it appears to be a thread deadlock. Here is a sample app that reproduces the problem.  We have also tried various java 7 builds and java8 pre-release.  We think we have found a couple workarounds, but we would like to understand why this code has problems on Mac.  Sample app with bug:

```
public class SampleFxInsideSwing
{  
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            new SampleFxInsideSwing().initFX(); 
        } 
    });    
}  

private void initFX() 
{
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    final JFXPanel stage = new JFXPanel();
    dialog.add(stage);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Button nextButton = new Button("Next");
            nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
            {
                //@Override 
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("Clicked");
                        AnchorPane parent = FXMLLoader.load(SampleFxInsideSwing.class.getResource("SampleFxml.fxml"));
                        Scene secondScene = new Scene(parent);
                        stage.setScene(secondScene);
                        System.out.println("Displaying second scene!");
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Group group = new Group();
            group.getChildren().add(nextButton);
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(group);
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        }
    });

    dialog.setVisible(true);
}   
}
```